# SQLite.NET Check if column exists in table

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, sqlite.net

I have created following method that Adds a column in an already existing SQLite table

```
public async void AddColumnMyNewColumn()
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
    await conn.ExecuteAsync("ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyNewColumn bit DEFAULT 'False';");
}
```

It creates a new column MyNewColumn in MyTable.

Next time when AddColumnMyNewColumn method is called, then it throws an error.

How to check if this column is already created??

I've cheched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354696/alter-table-sqlite-how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-before-alter-the-table),and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520945/sqlite-if-column-exists), but I cant put these things together to get something like this..

```
public async void AddColumnMyNewColumn()
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
    bool columnExists;

    //Check if column exists & set columnExists accordingly

    if(!columnExists)
        await conn.ExecuteAsync("ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyNewColumn bit DEFAULT 'False';");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution 1. Using SQLite.Net

You are using SQLite.Net, so your Tables are mapped to C# Classes, right?

And if you add a Property to your C# Class you can just call this

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path); 

await conn.CreateTableAsync<MyTableClass>();
```

and your new property will be added as a column to your Table, all previous data  will not be changed

Solution 2. Using a query

(to list all columns of a table) and then you could add your column manually)

[SQLite Schema Information Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460671/sqlite-schema-information-metadata)

Comment: Nice answer. I have one more issue regarding the same. Please Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208685/sqlite-net-c-sharp-equivalent-for-sqlite-bit-datatype

Comment: what happens if you rename an existing column and execute createtableasync method? will this create a new column and keep old one or update the name of the column? or even same question if you change the type of the existing column?

Answer (score 5):

With SQLite.net it´s easy to know if a column exists, in case you really need it:

```
var tableInfo = connection.GetTableInfo("YourTable");
var columnExists = tableInfo.Any(x => x.Name.Equals("ColumnName"));
```

But as mentioned before, `connection.CreateTable<T>()` or `connection.CreateTableAsync<T>()` will add the new columns for you, so you don´t need to execute sql statements.